# Axis2 : How AxisServlet is invoking the skelton part?

Tags: web-services, apache, apache-axis

I am developing webservices using Apache Axis2 (1.5) version .

I have developed a war file for webservice  client .
And Deployed my Webservice in (.aar) format  into axis2.war services directory.

This is working fine , but i could not understand the flow how my servlet (client ) is invoking the stub and in turn calling the skelton .

I have seen AxisServlet is responsible for this .
Could anybody please tell me , how this invoking happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit complicated one. Axis2servlet is considered as the transport receiver and this picture shows flow in abstract[1]. This article[2] and the referenced links also provides some information about that.

You can read those articles and have some debugging your selves to understand
 that properly.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7t54.png

[2] http://wso2.org/library/articles/extending-axis2